# How to Add Go Back function in WebView inside Fragment ? (duplicate)

Tags: android

The current code is not working , I want to add goback feature in webview, when I press back button in mobile . How can I solve it? Below is my current fragment . Guide me :)  found some question regarding same ,but didn't get the answer..

SOLVED! THIS IS WHAT I FOUND !!

```js
///MY FRAGMENT

}

public static WebView getWebView(){
return webView;  
}

}


----------------------


///MY ACTIVITY



@Override
 public void onBackPressed() {
  
  WebView webView = fbfragment.getWebView();

  if (webView.canGoBack()) {
   webView.goBack();

  } else {

   Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

   builder.setTitle("Exit").setMessage("Are you sure you want to exit?").setCancelable(false)
     .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
      public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
       finish();
      }
     }).setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

      @Override
      public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
      }
     });

   AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
   alert.setCancelable(false);
   alert.show();

  }

 }
}
```

```js
       package XXXX.XXXXXXXXXX.XXXXXXXXXXXX.com;
    
    import android.content.Context;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
    import android.util.Log;
    import android.view.LayoutInflater;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.ViewGroup;
    import android.webkit.CookieManager;
    import android.webkit.CookieSyncManager;
    import android.webkit.JavascriptInterface;
    import android.webkit.WebView;
    import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
    import XXXX.XXXXXX.XXXXXX..R;
    import XXXX.XXXXXX.XXXXXX..R.id;
    import XXXX.XXXXXX.XXXXXX.R.layout;
    
    
    public class FBFragment extends Fragment {
    
     private static final String target_url = "https://XXXXXXXXXX.com/";
     private static WebView webView;
     final Context context = getActivity();
     View rootView;
    
    
    
     @Override
     public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
       Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    
      rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.XXXXX_main, container, false);
    
      
    
      webView = (WebView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.webview);
      webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
      
      ...........CONT...
      
     
      
      
      
      
      
      
      
      
      .......CODE ENDS WITH..........
      
       }
      });
      CookieSyncManager.createInstance(getActivity());
      CookieManager cookieManager = CookieManager.getInstance();
      cookieManager.setAcceptCookie(true);
      CookieSyncManager.getInstance().startSync();
    
      webView.loadUrl(target_url);
    
      return rootView;
     }
    
     @JavascriptInterface
     public void processVideo(final String vidData, final String vidID) {
    
    
    
    
     }
    
    
    
     public static boolean Back() {
      if (webView.canGoBack()) {
       webView.goBack();
       return true;
      } else
       return false;
     }
    }
```

BELOW IS MY MAIN ACTIVITY

```js
  @Override
  public void onBackPressed() {
 

  AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

  builder.setTitle("Exit").setMessage("Are you sure you want to exit?").setCancelable(false)
    .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
     public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
      finish();
     }
    }).setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

     @Override
     public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
     }
    });

  AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
  alert.setCancelable(false);
  alert.show();

 }

}
```

Comment: Where your Back() function triggered? Where you calling it?

Comment: activity updated bro. please check

Answer (score 0):

Try below solutions

in your activity class's onBackPressed method call your fragment's Back() method.

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed()
{
    yourFragment.Back();
}
```

in your fragment's Back() method call getActivity().onBackPressed(); like this

```
    public static void Back() {
        if (webView.canGoBack()) {
            webView.goBack();
        } else{
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
            builder.setTitle("Exit").setMessage("Are you sure you want to exit?").setCancelable(false)
            .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                    getActivity().finish();
                }
            }).setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                }
            });

           AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
           alert.setCancelable(false);
           alert.show();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Bro, Now i'm getting this error "Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method Back() from the type myFragment" :(

Comment: Now im getting two errors , in fragment its showing "Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method getActivity() from the type Fragment"

and in activity "The method Back() is undefined for the type myFragment"  :(

Comment: @ Ekundayo Blessing Funminiyi , 

Now again showing two errors in

1.  [ WebView webView = fbFragment.getWebView();]  "fbFragment cannot be resolved"

2. [public void getWebView(){
   return webview; ]  "webview cannot be resolved to a variable"


:(

Answer (score 0):

Override the onBackPressed() of your Activity

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed()
{ 
 //fbFragment is an instance of your FBFragment
 WebView webView = fbFragment.getWebView();

 if (webView.canGoBack()) 
        {
            webView.goBack();

        } else{
          super.onBackPressed();

}

}
```

/// this is inside your fragment. NOTE the getWebview method

```
package XXXX.XXXXXXXXXX.XXXXXXXXXXXX.com;

import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.webkit.CookieManager;
import android.webkit.CookieSyncManager;
import android.webkit.JavascriptInterface;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
import XXXX.XXXXXX.XXXXXX..R;
import XXXX.XXXXXX.XXXXXX..R.id;
import XXXX.XXXXXX.XXXXXX.R.layout;


public class FBFragment extends Fragment {

    private static final String target_url = "https://XXXXXXXXXX.com/";
    private static WebView webView;
    final Context context = getActivity();
    View rootView;



    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.XXXXX_main, container, false);



        webView = (WebView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.webview);
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

        ...........CONT...










        .......CODE ENDS WITH..........

            }
        });
        CookieSyncManager.createInstance(getActivity());
        CookieManager cookieManager = CookieManager.getInstance();
        cookieManager.setAcceptCookie(true);
        CookieSyncManager.getInstance().startSync();

        webView.loadUrl(target_url);

        return rootView;
    }

    @JavascriptInterface
    public void processVideo(final String vidData, final String vidID) {




    }
public void getWebView(){
  return webview;  
 }
```

Comment: Goot this errors .. The method onBackPressed() of type FBFragment must override or implement a supertype method

The method onBackPressed() is undefined for the type Fragment

Comment: @Ekundayo Blessing Funminiyi How can you override onBackPressed method in fragment? Fragment doesn't have onBackPressed() method.

Comment: Apologies, I meant you should override that of the activity. I will edit the code now.